# How can I add import from src folder

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I have a folder `_files` directly inside `src` folder in angular application. `_files` folder has a json `_productlist.json`. I want to use `_productlist.json` but I am unable to add this path to import.

In `compilerOptions`, I have added `baseUrl": "./src"`. I tried adding these options but not working

```
import { foo } from '_files'
import { foo } from './_files'
import { foo } from './src/_files'
```

How can I successfully import to use json file?

Comment: Did you try files.json?

Comment: @Arun205 - what should I try?

Comment: with the file extension. '_files.json'

Answer (score 0):

you can modify paths field in your tsconfig.json to create import alias

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
   ....

   "paths": {
     "_files/*": ["_files/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

now you can import it like this

```
import { foo } from '_files/_productlist';
```

Comment: I have added `paths` in `tsconfig.json` file still same issue. FYI  I have removed `src` from baseUrl as I was getting error in other imports which starts from `nodemodules`.

Comment: in this case path would be `"_files/*": ["src/_files/*"]

Comment: I was getting warning, I used `"resolveJsonModule": true,` in `tsconfig.json` file, now right side code is working but left side foo showing error  `..._productlist.json` file has no exported member `foo`.

Comment: because it has no `foo` exported. I thought this was a generic name and you want help with creating a reference to the file. now you have the reference, what problem you want to get help with?

Comment: I want like this, can u pl check this https://jsonworld.com/demo/how-to-read-local-json-file-in-angular

Comment: will `import data from '_files/_productlist';` work as you like?

Comment: Data is not present in current context.

Comment: Use double dot instead of single dot

Answer (score 0):

In compilerOptions in tsconfig.json, use "baseUrl": "./"
instead of baseUrl": "./src".

Then you can import files as below:
import { foo } from 'src/_files/_productlist';